# Auto numbering in MS CRM

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I know it's an old discussion but still an open one.

Scenario is simple you have an entity say account which contains a attribute named "AccountId"
which should be auto incremented.

A prime candidate for this is Plugin registered on Pre event.

There are differnt options available to cater this.

- Get max number, increment it and assign to AccountId attribute.
- Rely on Some external source e.g. some web service or db to perform this job. (Which is not a good approach)

These approaches are [disccused here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/crm/archive/2008/05/13/auto-numbers-in-microsoft-dynamics-crm.aspx).

Personally I am in favour of Approach 1 but I have concerns:

1- Duplication on concurent requests

Locking and mutex can reduce that but what can be done to avoid this problem in case of "Farm environment"?

Answer (score 3):

The problem in a 'Farm environment', which actually means multiple servers with the front-end role installed, is that your are hardly able to avoid the duplication of your counter values.

With locks or mutexes, your are only able to achieve consistency in a single machine environment.

If you need reliable numbering, you should use either a service which generates the numbers or a dedicated database (that means, not the CRM database as this would be not supported) as back-end where you could coordinate the requests with locks.

Comment: Correct. Locks and mutex does not work in a in multi-server environment. The way to go is a web service for numbering generation.